# Not able to install jenssegers/mongodb on Laravel Framework 5.5.50, MongoDB server version: 3.6.8

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, ubuntu, driver

This error I'm gettign while installing this package. `$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb`

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb dev-develop -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[dev-develop].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.50
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.50
```

When I am trying to install `$ sudo pecl install mongodb` Then I'm getting

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
pecl/mongodb is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.9.0
install failed
```

[image]

Comment: try `composer require jenssegers/mongodb "^3.3.0"`  https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#laravel-version-compatibility

Comment: Hello Sir. Thank you for the reply. It's now installed but now it is showing this error.
'Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found' from laravel.

Comment: where your getting error ? on cmd?

Comment: No sir, I have some laravel apis. In that i'm importing 

**use MongoDB\Client as Mongo;**

Then I'm using a function to connect with mongdb

**public function activity() { 
  $conn = new Mongo();
 }**

Here when i am calling this api via postman i am getting that error.

Comment: Please start with a [mcve], which includes at least your `composer.json`. Also look at the possible options for `composer install`, maybe you need to upgrade/downgrade other packages. Also, can you please provide the whole output? Typically, there's more context info.

Comment: I've attached that postman output sir. Can you please check? It seems my driver is not there. But I have that **extentsion=mongodb.so** enabled in php.ini. There is one command to install driver **sudo pecl install mongodb** But it is also showing some error that i mentioned in the question. Thanks in advance!